# Django Model Some problems

Tags: django, database, postgresql, django-models

I'm Shimul,
I've been working with Django for about 1 year - but I'm having a project problem with a problem -
When I create a model - e.g.

```
class postmodel(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    blog_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255,unique=True)
```

Then I migrated the model.

after migrating my Model [**blog_slug**] field I want to delete.

When I migrate the model again - and then an error occurs in the database.

The error is that the field named [**blog_slug**] was not found,

**I don't want to delete my database - I want to [blog _slug] remove it.**

What can be done to avoid this problem -

Comment: Does column `blog_slug` exist in table you want to alter?

Comment: After migrating, what are you deleting? `blob_slug` field? how did you delete that? Have you deleted any file in `migrations` directory?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in development mode and you want to delete `blob_slug`, remove that field from models and remove database (sqlite probably), pycache files, migations documents ( do not delete migration folder and init.py files)

Then exit virtualenv and run server again.

Comment: I don't want to delete my database - I want to [blog _slug] remove it.

Comment: I think,normally after removing a field from model , migrations remove it from database. if your slugs might used as pk it may have problem removing it,